# what's the difference between list_to_binary and iolist_to_binary?

Tags: erlang

I only know `list_to_binary` in erlang otp, but today I see `iolist_to_binary`?

I tried it in erlang shell, but I can't find the difference.

```
(ppb1_bs6@esekilvxen263)59> list_to_binary([<<1>>, [1]]).
<<1,1>>
(ppb1_bs6@esekilvxen263)60> iolist_to_binary([<<1>>, [1]]).
<<1,1>>
(ppb1_bs6@esekilvxen263)61> iolist_to_binary([<<1>>, [1], 1999]).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  iolist_to_binary/1
        called as iolist_to_binary([<<1>>,[1],1999])
(ppb1_bs6@esekilvxen263)62> list_to_binary([<<1>>, [1], 1999]).  
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  list_to_binary/1
        called as list_to_binary([<<1>>,[1],1999])
(ppb1_bs6@esekilvxen263)63> list_to_binary([<<1>>, [1], <<1999>>]).
<<1,1,207>>
(ppb1_bs6@esekilvxen263)64> ioslist_to_binary([<<1>>, [1], <<1999>>]).
** exception error: undefined shell command ioslist_to_binary/1
(ppb1_bs6@esekilvxen263)65> iolist_to_binary([<<1>>, [1], <<1999>>]). 
<<1,1,207>>
```

From the test, I think `iolist_to_binary` may be the same as `list_to_binary`.

Answer (score 5):

In current versions of Erlang/OTP both functions will automatically flatten the list or iolist() you provide, leaving functionally only one difference, which is that list_to_binary/1 will not accept a binary parameter, but iolist_to_binary/1 will:

```
1> erlang:iolist_to_binary(<<1,2,3>>). 
<<1,2,3>>

2> erlang:list_to_binary(<<1,2,3>>).  
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  list_to_binary/1
        called as list_to_binary(<<1,2,3>>)
```

This is clear from the type specification of iolist():

```
maybe_improper_list(byte() | binary() | iolist(), binary() | [])
```

As you can see, iolist() can be a binary, but clearly a list can never be a binary.

If you want to follow through the convolution of the improper list type you can find its definition, along with iolist() at [(Erlang) Types and Function Specifications](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html).

In terms of practical use iolist() is a messy or unflattened list. Think of it as a kind of lazy output, deliberately not flattened to be a proper list by the produver as an optimisation because not every consumer will need to flatten it. You can see what it looks like by checking the output of io_lib:format/2:

```
1> io_lib:format("Hello ~s ~b!~n", ["world", 834]).
    [72,101,108,108,111,32,"world",32,"834",33,"\n"]
```

Or:

```
2> io:format("~w~n", [  io_lib:format("Hello ~s ~b!~n", ["world", 834])  ]).
    [72,101,108,108,111,32,[119,111,114,108,100],32,[56,51,52],33,[10]]
```

I notice that many of your examples include the number 1999. Attempts to convert any list or iolist() which contain any number that is greater than 255 to a binary will always fail by the way:

```
8> erlang:list_to_binary([1,2,3,255]).  
<<1,2,3,255>>
9> erlang:list_to_binary([1,2,3,256]).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  list_to_binary/1
        called as list_to_binary([1,2,3,256])
```

This is because it wants to create a list of bytes from your list, and a number above 255 is ambiguous in terms of its possible byte representation; it can't be known if you mean little endian or big endian, etc (see [(Wikipedia) Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

Answer (score 2):

The differences are not large. Type checking is done. But in the end caused by one and the same function. If I correctly found.

Source list_to_binary (https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/emulator/beam/binary.c#L896):

```
BIF_RETTYPE list_to_binary_1(BIF_ALIST_1)
{
    return erts_list_to_binary_bif(BIF_P, BIF_ARG_1, bif_export[BIF_list_to_binary_1]);
}
```

Source iolist_to_binary (https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/emulator/beam/binary.c#L903):

```
BIF_RETTYPE iolist_to_binary_1(BIF_ALIST_1)
{
    if (is_binary(BIF_ARG_1)) {
    BIF_RET(BIF_ARG_1);
    }
    return erts_list_to_binary_bif(BIF_P, BIF_ARG_1, bif_export[BIF_iolist_to_binary_1]);
}
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by adding links to the source files on Github, for future reference. One wonders why `iolist_to_binary/1` is a BIF at all; the same code could have been written in pure Erlang.

Answer (score 0):

`iolist_to_binary` - converts iolist to binary

for your ref:
http://www.erlangpatterns.org/iolist.html 
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html